# Trigger error 3616 on alter table add column

Tags: sql-server, triggers, alter

I'm experiencing what I think is a weird error when trying to alter a table, because I haven't been able to find any other examples of it occurring.  The environment is MSSQL server 2008 R2, and I'm running the following script.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[device_letters] 
ADD [accountnum] [char] (13) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
```

The alter is failing with the following error.

> Msg 3616, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.

What's confusing is that there are no triggers involved in the script, obviously, nor are there any triggers on the table. I can't even find any triggers that reference the table. The only item that references this table is a stored procedure that is not actively running. There are no open transactions that I can see. It's a QA environment, so it's not under heavy load, either, and this script worked fine in other environments, including a different QA box and production.

Comment: Presumably coming from a database trigger. DDL trigger.

Comment: Error looks like there is a DDL trigger that fails, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: check in ssms under `database triggers`.

Comment: That was it - someone snuck in a DDL trigger for CDC that doesn't exist on any other environment.  Thanks, all.